Rich text editor Scroll problem not showing box
SafeArea(child:  SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child:  Container(
                height: 220,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 50, // Set the desired toolbar height
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          left: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                          right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                          top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                        ), //,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                      ),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: QuillToolbar.simple(
                          configurations: QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
                            controller: _controller,
                            sharedConfigurations: const QuillSharedConfigurations(
                              locale: Locale('de'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: _scrollToBottom,
                        child:  Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(
                              left: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                              right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                            ), // No top border// Add border to the editor
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: _scrollToBottom,
                              child: QuillEditor.basic(
                                configurations: QuillEditorConfigurations(
                                  placeholder: 'Message',
                                  scrollable: true,
                                  controller: _controller,
                                  readOnly: false,
                                  scrollBottomInset: 150,
                                  //autoFocus: true,
                                  sharedConfigurations: const QuillSharedConfigurations(
                                    locale: Locale('de'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
),

This is my code this editor as a text box in below of screen when we want to open the keyboard to write something then box has been hide and not showing anything when we scroll screen then showing that box.
we want to say any functionality when we click on that box scroll automatically and show that box .
